# which/whereis differences

Tags: unix, terminal, path, which

What's the difference between `which` and `whereis` ?

Comment: I'm sorry but on my 10.5.8 OS X system which and whereis **always** give the same results. Maybe this *is* a very OS X specific question, since I agree, a different result is expected. Maybe whereis does not comply to what it should do. At least the two examples (see below) are not working: whereis ls and whereis php always give the same result as which ...

Can anybody confirm this? Does Snow Leopard behave the same?

Comment: Yeah I know, thats why I asked this question.

Comment: @mk12 I feel like `type` is superior. It also knows about defined aliases, functions etc

Answer (score 176, accepted):

How about learning about `whereis` and `which` using `whatis`?

```
$  whatis which
which                (1)  - shows the full path of (shell) commands

$  whatis whereis
whereis              (1)  - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command
```

Basically, `whereis` searches for "possibly useful" files, while `which` only searches for executables.

I rarely use `whereis`. On the other hand, `which` is very useful, specially in scripts. `which` is the answer for the following question: *Where does this command come from?*

```
$  which ls
/bin/ls

$  whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1p/ls.1p.bz2 /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.bz2
```

Comment: There's more to it than that. On my system, whereis and which return different executable paths. I can only get the path to the one that actually runs with `whereis`, not the one for `which`.

Comment: @JordanReiter: It can't be! `which` shows the actual path. Are you sure the path pointed by `which` isn't just a symlink to the path pointed by `whereis`? Maybe it is a shell alias. In bash, try running `type your_cmd_here`.

Comment: @DenilsonSá unfortunately I can't recreate the situation but when I run into it again I'll provide more details.

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia, I get the same thing.
```$ type xcodebuild -->
xcodebuild is hashed (/usr/local/bin/xcodebuild)
$ which xcodebuild -->
/usr/local/bin/xcodebuild
$ whereis xcodebuild -->
/usr/bin/xcodebuild```

And running `xcodebuild` always picks the wrong one (i.e., the `/usr/bin` command) even though `/usr/local/bin` has higher `$PATH` priority.

Comment: I have mutliple python installations. Some in `/usr/bin/python2.7`, some in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4`. `whereis python` finds them both which is a great way to list all python versions installed

Comment: `which ls` and `whereis ls` show the same results for me, on OSX 10.15.4

Comment: On macOS, `whereis` searches only for _programs_ and not man pages or sources; it does this in "standard binary directories"; while `which` searches for programs in current `PATH`. Of course, macOS isn't *nix strictly.

Answer (score 29):

`whereis` searches the standard *nix locations for a specified command.

`which` searches your user-specific PATH (which may include some of the locations whereis searches, and may not include others - it might also include some places that `whereis` doesn't search if you'd added to your PATH)

Comment: Unix, Linux etc. (Mac OS X belonging in the etc.)

Comment: Nope. Just a fairly common convention of creative wildcard use to refer to a family of similar operating systems. ;)

Comment: Yes! For a good example, compare: `PATH='' /usr/bin/which vim` vs `PATH='' /usr/bin/whereis vim`. The `whereis` command still locates the executable, even if your PATH is empty.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting their man pages :

**[whereis](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?whereis) :**

> whereis locates source/binary and
>   manuals sections for specified files.

For instance :

```
$ whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

ie, the "php" executable, and some other stuff (like man pages).

and **[which](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which) :**

> which returns the pathnames of the
>   files which would be executed in the
>   current environment

For instance :

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

ie, only the "php" executable.

Answer (score 2):

***which*** search for executables in the directories specified by the environment variable PATH. And if found out, the full pathname of this executable will be printed.

> $ which ls
>   /bin/ls
>   $ which ifconfig
>   $ # No output, because ifconfig only exist in root's PATH.

***whereis*** search for executables, source files, and manual pages using a database built by system automatically.

> $ whereis less
>   less: /bin/less /usr/bin/less /usr/bin/X11/less /usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz

But it seems that ***whereis*** and ***locate*** don't use the same database. When I installed a software and then used ***whereis*** and ***locate*** immediately to search for this software. The result is that ***whereis*** could find out some files related to this software while ***locate*** couldn't. Do they really use different database? How the database work? --Well, how about refuse to be a pedant? :)

Comment: did you run updatedb command? locate relies on that as far as I remember

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share something I learned recently on my **Apple MacOS** X Mojave; pretty sure it applies to numerous versions of Apple's macOS over the past few years:

On Mojave:

- `whereis` searches for executables **only** in the path defined by the string `user.cs_path`; further defined as: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.
- `whereis` displays **no information** on any system documentation (i.e. `man` pages).
- On some systems, `sysctl` may be used to "set or get kernel state", but Apple has **deprecated** the `-w, --write` option for changing `user.cs_path` using `sysctl`.
- In effect, Apple has relegated `whereis` to reporting the location of the 10-20 year-old tools they provide to their customers in `user.cs_path`.
- All of this *may make* Apple's `whereis` the most useless utility on the planet.

Just in case you're  interested  :)