# "which" and "whereis"

Tags: linux

On my linux box, after typing `which java`, I get

> /usr/bin/java

After typing `whereis java`, I get

> java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

What are the meanings of these two results? When setting up the JAVA_HOME, which one should I use?

Comment: What is your `JAVA_HOME` currently set to?

Answer (score 4):

From [which/whereis differences](https://superuser.com/questions/40301/which-whereis-differences)

```
which   (1) - shows the full path of (shell) commands
whereis (1) - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command
```

I'd use `which` as it shows you where just the binary is as I assume that is all you need. However Java could be installed somewhere else and `which` would not report it as it only searches for an executable or script in the directories listed in the environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: Note that `whereis` on Linux always uses a hard-coded list of directories, while `which` uses the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

`which <executable>` returns the first found executable on you PATH. In other words, what would be executed if `<executable>` were entered as a command.

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_HOME` should be a parent folder which contains the JDK or JRE, or in other words, it has `/lib`, `/bin` etc. folders from the Java distribution which contain libraries/dependencies for Java Runtime as well as executables. In your case it appears that `/usr/share/java` would be the best fit - check to see if it has subfolders from the distribution in there.

`which` command returns the first executable match, while `whereis` locates the other matches along with executable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exerpt from man whereis :

```
  whereis  -  locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command
```

So the second line you get contains both the binary location but also resources used by this app like the man page location, and sources...

If you want to set your `PATH`, it should point to `/usr/bin/`

If you want to set `JAVA_HOME` in order to get a real environment development in linux, I suggest you manually maintain your java jdk.

At home, I install java's jdk in `/usr/local/java/jdk1.6...`

and I make a symlink in `/usr/local/java/jdk` that points to the desired jdk.

My JAVA_HOME variable always point to `/usr/local/java/jdk`

Distros don't do a satisfying job to build a really good java environment for devs to my mind.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

None of those.

JAVA_HOME should point to the root folder of your JDK

on my system:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm

$ ll /etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 mai   16  2009 /etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm -> /usr/lib/jvm/sun-jdk-1.6
```